# i2c dispaly not showing the output arduino(ESP32)

Tags: arduino, display, esp32, i2c, arduino-c++

```
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>
#include <Adafruit_SH110X.h>
#include <ThreeWire.h>  
#include <RtcDS1302.h>

ThreeWire myWire(4,5,2); // IO, SCLK, CE
RtcDS1302<ThreeWire> Rtc(myWire);

#define SCREEN_WIDTH 128 // OLED display width, in pixels
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 64 // OLED display height, in pixels
#define i2c_Address 0x3c // initialize with the I2C addr 0x3C Typically eBay OLED's
#define OLED_RESET -1   // QT-PY / XIAO

Adafruit_SH1106G display = Adafruit_SH1106G(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, &Wire, OLED_RESET);

// define the sunrise and sunset times
int sunrise_hour = 6;
int sunset_hour = 18;

void setup() {
  Rtc.Begin();
  delay(250); // wait for the OLED to power up
  display.begin(i2c_Address, true); // Address 0x3C default
  display.clearDisplay();
  display.setTextSize(1);
  display.setTextColor(SH110X_WHITE);
  display.setCursor(2, 2);
  display.println("Calendar");
  display.display();
}

void loop() {
  // get the current date and time
  unsigned int year, month, day;
  unsigned int hour, minute, second;
  RtcDateTime now = Rtc.GetDateTime();
  year = now.Year();
  month = now.Month();
  day = now.Day();
  hour = now.Hour();
  minute = now.Minute();
  second = now.Second();

  // clear the display and set the cursor to the top left corner
  display.clearDisplay();
  display.setCursor(0, 0);

  // calculate the position of the sun based on the current time
  int sun_x = (hour * 12) + (minute / 5); // 12 pixels per hour, 1 pixel every 5 minutes
  int sun_y = (SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2) - abs(6 - minute % 12); // move up and down in a sine wave pattern

  // calculate the position of the moon based on the current time
  int moon_x = (hour * 12) + (minute / 5);
  int moon_y = (SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2) + abs(6 - minute % 12) + 20; // move down in a sine wave pattern

  // check if it's before sunrise or after sunset
  if (hour < sunrise_hour || hour >= sunset_hour) {
    // draw the moon
    int moon_size = 8;
    int moon_color = SH110X_WHITE;
    display.fillCircle(moon_x, moon_y, moon_size, moon_color);
  } else {
    // draw the sun
    int sun_size = 10;
    int sun_color = SH110X_WHITE;
    display.fillCircle(sun_x, sun_y, sun_size, sun_color);
  }

  // display the changes on the OLED
  display.display();
  
  delay(1000); // wait for 1 second
}
```

I wrote a small program to show the movement of the sun and moon according to time. But the screen stays blank nothing is showing on display. There are no hardware or connection problems. The RTC module and Display are working fine. I ran some example clock programs. The time and date are shown on display. But I cant find why this is not working

Answer (score 1):

The OLED display is updated by sending commands and data over the I2C bus to the display controller chip. This takes some time, and if the program updates the display too quickly, it may not have enough time to finish updating before the next update cycle starts.

Try Increasing your delay to 5000ms, instead 1000ms.

> // display the changes on the OLED
> display.display();
> delay(5000); // wait for 5 seconds

By adding a delay after each update cycle, the program gives the OLED display enough time to finish updating before starting the next cycle. This ensures that the display is updated correctly and reduces the likelihood of visual artifacts or flickering on the display.

This may help to resolve the issue where the display is not showing anything. This delay can be adjusted as needed based on the requirements of your program and the speed of the display update.

(Also check your I2C address with serial debug). Good luck